# How to match similar documents in R

Tags: r, twitter, text-mining

I have created two corpuses: one containing tweet texts and another containing company names. What I'm trying to do is find which companies are mentioned in tweets.

Example document of a tweet:

```
> writeLines(as.character(tweet_corp[[175]]))
general motor send mexican made model chevi cruze us car dealer tax free across border make usaor pay big border tax
```

Example document of a company:

```
> writeLines(as.character(company_corp[[1397]]))
general motor
```

I would like an output that matches tweet_corp[[175]] with company_corp[[1397]]. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `stringr` package to check whether a company name occurs in a tweet, e.g.

```
library(stringr)

company_name <- "general motor"

tweet <- "general motor send mexican made model chevi cruze us car dealer tax free across border make usaor pay big border tax"

# check whether a company name occurs in a string
str_detect(
  string = tweet,
  pattern = coll(company_name)
)
```